# What Does >> mean in Python?

Tags: python, wiegand

Someone sent me this equation but I don't understand what it means.

```
result = ((~c1) >> 1) & 0x0FFFFFF
```

It has to do with converting the binary from a wiegand reader.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538472/wiegand-rfid-reader-vs-usb-rfid-reader-raspberry-pi)

Comment: I searched all over stackoverflow for that "duplicate" answer and it never came up

Comment: I googled for bitwise operators in Python to find it - Google still doesn't search non-alphabetic characters very well, for some reason...

Comment: well i didnt know it was called a bitwise operator. I just searched for operators in python. Thanks though.

Comment: No prob. It's not your fault, you have to already know the answer to find the dupe. Read [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) for a pretty good intro to bitwise operations. Wikipedia is also good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `>>` operator in Python is a bitwise right-shift.  If your number is 5, then its binary representation is 101.  When right-shifted by 1, this becomes 10, or 2.  It's basically dividing by 2 and rounding down if the result isn't exact.

Your example is bitwise-complementing `c1`, then right-shifting the result by 1 bit, then masking off all but the 24 low-order bits.

Comment: Thank you for answering what the rest of the equation does.

Comment: I think that last part of the equation is what is dropping my initial zeros. Take a look at my other question. Maybe its related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535905/python-reading-wiegand-dropping-zeros

Comment: Yes, the `&` operator is bitwise-AND.  It will zero all bits that are not 1 in both operands.  So with an operand of `0xFFFFFF`, it's keeping the low-order 24 bits of the other operand, and forcing the rest to zero.

Answer (score 1):

This statement means:

```
result =                                # Assign a variable
          ((~c1)                        # Invert all the bits of c1
                 >> 1)                  # Shift all the bits of ~c1 to the right
                        & 0x0FFFFFF;    # Usually a mask, perform an & operator
```

The `~` operator does a [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Example:

```
m = 0b111
x  =   0b11001
~x ==  0b11010      # Performs Two's Complement
x >> 1#0b1100
m ==   0b00111
x ==   0b11001      # Here is the "and" operator. Only 1 and 1 will pass through
x & m #0b    1
```

Comment: Does & 0x0FFFFFF strip off any leading zeros?

Comment: @swg1cor14 Yes it does, let me edit my example.

Comment: Take a look at my other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535905/python-reading-wiegand-dropping-zeros. I think this is related.